# How to POST data to php from ash (bash)

Tags: php, linux, bash, openwrt, ash

I have url (www.blabla.web.id/proses_data.php) online. And I want to submit data to that url from my bash script. I'm using ash, bash inside *OpenWRT*.

I'm trying this technique,

```
#!/bin/sh
elinks -dump http://www.blabla.web.id/proses_data.php?data=thisisthedata
```

But it use `GET` method. How to use `POST` method?

Comment: you can use cUrl instead so that you can do POST, GET, HEAD, etc

Comment: try [`curl`](http://man.cx/curl) ?

Comment: can't I use elinks? is there POST/GET/Head option for elinks?

Comment: ^^Did you try to find it - option for `elinks`? (Do you have a specific reason for not using `curl`? say, your linux distro is a tiny one & does not have it?)

Comment: @rezafahlevi08 do you know what elinks? elinks is a console web browser like lynx. it doesn't allow you to send different HTTP request

Answer (score 2):

[elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/about.html) is a program for browsing the web in text mode. you may not post data throgh it.

but Linux provide beautiful tools for POST data

with this nice and little command

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/resource
```

Also POST if web response in JSON then

```
curl -X POST  -H "Accept: Application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://someHostName/someEndpoint -d '{"id":"IDVALUE","name":"Mike"}' | grep }| python -mjson.tool
```

Aslo some little trick here

Add this function in `php` script

```
function getInput() {
  $fr = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
  while (!feof ($fr)) {
    $input .= fgets($fr);
  }
  fclose($fr);
  return $input;
}

$takethis = getInput();
```

Now in bash do like

```
echo 22333333 | php my.php
```